# Subtraction problems in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

If one subtracts 5 from 8.8, the actual result is: **3.8** but in my code it gives **3.8000000007**. 
 Why it this? Could anyone kindly provide a valuable insight?
 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's working :

```js
var p = 8.8 - 5;
console.log(p.toFixed(1));
```

Comment: You can check it now

Answer (score 0):

In the below picture, Calculation part is there. Kindly Check it.

[image]

Comment: `yMin = (yMin-interval).toFixed(1);`

Answer (score 0):

> The Javascript Engine is only trying to help you out. If it finds a Floating Point Number amongst the Numbers supplied in your Arithmetic Operations, it will automatically parse the Result to a Floating Point Number as well - (with the highest possible Precision). 
>   
> Therefore, to get around this *Eager but Unsolicited Help of the Javascript Engine*; you'd need to manually call: `toFixed()` on the Resulting Value like so:

```
    var p = 8.8 - 5;
    console.log( p.toFixed(1) ); //<== 3.8
```

Alternatively, You may extend the Number Prototype and add your Unique Functionality if that is what you desire. However, **this is not at all advised!!!**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

        Number.prototype.precise = function(){
            return this.toFixed(1);
        };

        Number.prototype.floatSubtract = function(num){
            return (this - num).toFixed(1);
        };

        var p1 = (8.8 - 5).precise();
        var p2 =  8.8.floatSubtract(5);

        console.log(p1);    //< 3.8
        console.log(p2);    //< 3.8
    </script>
```

Comment: How to get exact add up value,without using .toFixed().

Comment: @Jaya      As you can see; **this is a Javascript internal behaviour... a means of helping you out**. You may however add a Method to the Number Prototype (**not Advised**) to help do that for you. The Post has now been now updated to reflect this option as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is nothing wrong in using "toFixed()". Why you are looking for an answer without using it?

Nervertheless you could do it the mathematical way:

```js
var result = (8.8 * 10  - 5 * 10) / 10;
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I think this will be the solution.

```html
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
  <head>
       <script>
      num = 8.8 - 5;
         console.log(Math.round(num * 100) / 100)
       </script>
    </head>
</html>
```